# Css Black Bar Space

Tags: html, css

I have a really simple script.

**Index.html**

```
<!Doctype html>
<html>
    <title>Homepage</title>
    <head>
        <style>
            #topBlackBar {
                border-top: 50px solid #000;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="topBlackBar"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

I havent got the rest of the styling done for my page, but I do have a black top bar.
The problem is that there's a little white space between the toolbar and the black top bar.

Here is an example

How could I change the script to remove the whitespace.

Comment: It is a simple script I thought I should put the style attributes in the actual html page before moving it to a stylesheet. Also, the rest of my style isn't finished yet my top bar is

Comment: To be precise, there is no script in your code, it's only HTML and CSS, and none of these is a scripting language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this in your css

`body{margin:0;padding:0;}`

Answer (score 5):

The body of a page generally has margins and/or padding assigned to it by default. You can fix this particular issue by adding this CSS style:

```
body {
    margin:0;
}
```

I would recommend adding a CSS reset to your page as well. [Here is the one that I usually use](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/), this will reset all of the default values so that your styling will actually appear as defined.

Answer (score 1):

Reset your padding/margin that is default on the body element:

```
body{margin:0;padding:0;}
```

Comment: thanks it worked Id accept your answer by now but I have to wait ten minutes

Comment: Why first accept my answer and then 2 weeks later when someone places the exact same answer unaccept mine and accept the other one?

Answer (score 0):

`<div id="topBlackBar"/>` should be: `<div id="topBlackBar">content</div>` p.s. Where is your script sample?

Answer (score 0):

You can also add #topBlackBar { border: 0px; padding: 0px; } so that your image doesn't have any extra space around it.